# Running multiple Operating Systems at the same time in VMWare?

Tags: vmware

I want to run **Windows 7** and **Linux** at the same time in VMWare for different tasks.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Err, yes, VMWare actually *is* the solution to this problem. We quite often run VMs side by side. Other than memory requirements (I think VMWare allocates the memory in advance for a VM and that becomes unavailable elsewhere), we've had very little trouble doing just that.

Comment: @paxdiablo,do I need two vmware instances to run two OS,or just one instance ?

Comment: @mysql_go: you need two if you want to run them concurrently. You can dual boot in one but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @paxdiablo ,do you mean that if only one vmware instance,I need to close `win7` before running `linux` by `dual boot`?

Comment: @mysql_go: think of a VMWare instance just like a physical machine. You cannot run Linux and Windows concurrently on a physical machine (well, not without VMWare :-) ), so you can't do it in a VM either. Just create two distinct VMs, one for Linux, one for Windows. Then you can run them separately or concurrently as often as you want.

Comment: @paxdiablo,got it! But will the snapshots be lost if I use vmware this way?

Comment: @mysql_go: no, snapshots belong to an instance, they are preserved across invocations of that instance.

Comment: @paxdiablo,if snapshots belong to an instance,I think it'll lost,unless the snapshots belong to a `.vmk` file,which are separate per OS.